# How to write a request receiving data on films of one producer within the minimum and maximum budget

Tags: php, mysql, request, max, min

Please help with a MySQL query.

I have 2 tables:

producers in which just information about people and their id.

movies in which information about films is the 2 main fields budget and producer_id.

How to make a request so that when choosing a producer it finds the minimum and maximum value of the budget?

In the future, I want to transfer these values to the front-end where, when choosing a producer, films that fall into the value of min and max will be displayed

I created a gist with MySQL damp https://gist.github.com/annkarsk777/5f8c75dbef65a930c5399683955e310c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQL `MAX()` and `MIN()` functions to achieve this. Something like:

```sql
SELECT MAX(budget) as max, MIN(budget) AS min FROM movies where producer_id = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL MIN() and MAX() functions will work. You just have to pass the producer's ID to the query and it will work. In php, you can get the producer's ID and then pass in the query just as below.

```
$producer_id = 1;

$query = "SELECT MIN(budget) AS min, MAX(budget) as max FROM movies WHERE producer_id = '$producer_id'";
```

This query will give you the budget of a producer whose id is 1.